# Plot type or data transformation to visualize datasets with very high dispersion

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, cumulative-distribution-function, boxplot

I want to plot two datasets with the number of times an event happens within a month, based on a variable (changed/unchanged). The number of occurrences vary from 0 to 775,963. Many values (about 25% for the *unchanged* variable and 10% for the *changed* variable) are at 0. My problem is that because of the very high dispersion it is very hard to make a plot that provides useful information. For example bellow are the ECDF plot and the boxplot:

[image]

[image]

I would normally use logarithmic axis but because of the high number of zero values this is also not possible (?). One idea is to define a max value (e.g. 50) and use this max value for every value above it, but this seems very arbitrary.

Is there any suggested plot type for values with such high dispersion, or a transformation that can handle the zero values?

EDIT: I upload the data file in case anyone wants to play with it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8gk6yzds751eiy/updates-20160501.txt?dl=0

EDIT 2: Using log[x+1] as suggested by @GeoMatt22 is much better but it's very hard to tell the difference between 0 and 1 which is important for my case study.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $\log[1+x]$ is a common transform for count-type data, and maps 0 to 0.

Comment: Can you post the data for people to play with? Would using a set of plots be acceptable to represent the data? What are your goals for these visualizations? Are you exploring them for your own understanding, assessing a specific property (eg, checking model assumptions), presenting them to others to communicate or persuade? What piece of information do you want to glean from the plot[s]?

Comment: @gung Thanks! I edited the post to provide a link to the data. I mainly want to explore some assumptions (that *unchanged* have generally fewer updates than *changed*) and present it to my team to convince them about this assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If particular values, like you mentioned zero, are special you can customize your transformation for them. Log[x + 0.1], for instance would make 0 and 1 stand apart more.

Or you could make entirely custom bins, such as I've done here.

[image]

Even more than a log transformation, it loses the direct interpretability of seeing the raw data values, but our perception can't handle such wide scales anyway, and this gives you some sense of comparison between the two groups.

Here's a cumulative line chart version of the same bins.

[image]

Another technique is to combine a big picture view with a zoomed in view (not everything has to be in one graph!). Here's a box plot view showing everything except the extreme outlier. Note that jitter and transparency help some.

[image]

And here's a histogram zoomed in to about 0 - 500.

[image]

*(I didn't see any zeros in your data, so subtracted 1 from every value, thinking your uploaded data may have been in the plus-1 condition for logs.)*

Comment: Thanks for the examples @xan, they look great! Indeed your guess was correct, I had added 1 in every value. Which plotting tool did you use?

Comment: Great to hear. I'm using SAS [JMP](http://www.jmp.com/), an interactive stats application I work on.